# PHP refresh SQL Data sem fazer refresh a pagina

Tags: php

Eu tenho um site onde mostra dados da Database para a Pagina.

Se esses dados forem alterados na database, automaticamente ele vai mostrá-los na Pagina, sem fazer refresh a pagina, apenas faz refresh ao código em tempo real.

Utilizo o id='refresh' para tal equação, mas.. visto que não sei como fazer...

Como faço isso?

```
                 $steamID = $_SESSION['steamid'];

                $db = mysqli_connect($host, $username, $password, $dbname );
                // Check connection

                if (mysqli_connect_errno())
                {
                    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
                }
                $getC = mysqli_query($db,"SELECT credits, level, exp FROM users_steam WHERE steamid ='$steamID' ");

                while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($getC))
                {   
                    $exp = $row['exp'];
                    $lvl = $row['level'];

                   /* if($lvl == 100 && ($exp == 0)) {

                        $confirm = '';

                    } else {
                        $confirm = ' <span class="levels"> Exp </span>'. $exp;
                    }*/

                    echo "<li><a href='buy.php' alt='Silver Coins' id='refresh'><span class='currency-w'>" . number_format($row['credits'],0) . "</a></span></li>";
                    echo "<li><a href='profile.php'><span id='levels' class='levels'>level </span>" . $row['level'] . "</a></li>";
                    echo "<li></li>";

                }
```

Answer (score 0):

Resposta rápida.:

```
Não é possível apenas com PHP
```

Resposta mais elaborada.:

```
PHP é do lado do servidor e não do lado do cliente.
O que poderá fazer é utilizar uma linguagem do lado do cliente e fazer requisições ao servidor e atualizar apenas o conteúdo que pretende exemplo usar ajax do jquery.
```

Answer (score 0):

Voce pode fazer isso usando jQuery.

```
$.ajax({
  type: 'POST',
  url: 'CAMINHO DO SEU ARQUIVO PHP',
  success: function(data){
     // Retorno com data
  }

})
```